# Listeners return different results on different browsers even after clearing cache/cookies

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I believe Google Tag Manager is fairly new and nothing much is going on yet. I went all around Google looking for a solution, but simply gave up after trying all possible solutions. I'm using a Wordpress blog platform, and have integrated Universal Analytics and Google Tag Manager. The settings for my listeners are as follows:

**====Link Click Listener====**

[image: link click listener]

**====Outbound Link Click Tagger====**

[image: Outbound Link Click Tagger]

**====Outbound Link Rule====**

[image: Outbound Link Rule]

I used console to test the dataLayer, and it retrieves gtm.load, gtm.js and gtm.dom, but regardless of whatever I click, I see on my Google Analytics that the events are undefined even though I provided the necessary parameter to name them. However, when I tried to do it on a different browser, it works, but not completely (instead of outbound link, it will record it under click), or the outbound works for a completely random client on the Internet, returning the tag "outbound-link" but with an undefined action.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** I just noticed that there is a difference between a left-mouse-button click and a middle-mouse-button click. The middle one is not measured, whereas the left-mouse-button click is.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is an error in your rule. You want `"{{element url}} does not contain welink.com"` instead of just `{{url}}` (which would mean that the tag should not fire on your domain at all).

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I just tried it on Chrome, Incognito, FF, and Safari to test it out. I'm still not sure whether the "Click Listener" interferes with the "Link Click Listener".
The click listener is enabled to track buttons and JS calls through the site. Whereas the Link Click listener is deployed for the purpose of analyze user flow to our social media/outbound links. So far, only the clicks are recorded, but outbound links aren't.
Thanks again for the catch!